# Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity using knp paginator

Tags: symfony, doctrine, knppaginator

I have a question about knp paginator.
I use Symfony 2.8.
I made a table that has composite primary key, and corresponding list page using knp paginator.
I'm receiving the exception when I try to show.
"Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity"
I tried to inspect source files of knp paginator and doctrine.
So I found a workaround.

1)Set knp option "distinct" to false;

2)Set following hints to query.

- set "knp_paginator.count" to rows count of query result.
- set "knp_paginator.fetch_join_collection" to false -- this is neccessary.

Is this right way?
Are there potential problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you might encounter is posted here in [this related issue on GitHUB](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2910):

> The only "problem" is when your Paginator query calls for a fetch join to a collection. The work around for this is to use a regular join as mentioned above. The drawback is that your paginated entities will not be hydrated with the collection. The collection will have to be lazy-loaded when called upon.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I understand that the number of entities is different from the number of corresponding rows if use fetch join.

Comment: @Miwanoushi Yes, indeed this could lead to wrong page count for sure.