# T-SQL too expensive query with select in where/having condition and composite primary key

Tags: sql, t-sql, doctrine

I've created an http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8137/2 to show you the schema

I have three entities "Invoice"->1:n->"Payment"->1:n->"Taking"

Each entity has it's own Total (amount) and a sign that shows if i have to add or subtract a value.

The problem is that i can't find an efficient way to "SELECT" my invoices that have an open bill (the sum of takings differs from the amount of the invoice). 
I have thousands of records and these two selects take a lot of time to be executed (from 25 to 30 seconds).

Here the creation of the schema

```
CREATE TABLE Sign (
  sign_code INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  sign_value INT NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sign_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice (
    invoice_year int NOT NULL,
    invoice_number int NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    sign INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_year, invoice_number) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (sign) REFERENCES Sign(sign_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment (
    invoice_year int NOT NULL,
    invoice_number int NOT NULL,
    payment_row int NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    sign INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_year, invoice_number, payment_row), 
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_year, invoice_number) REFERENCES Invoice(invoice_year, invoice_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (sign) REFERENCES Sign(sign_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Taking (
    taking_year int NOT NULL,
    taking_row INT NOT NULL,
    invoice_year int NOT NULL,
    invoice_number int NOT NULL,
    payment_row int NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    sign INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (taking_year, taking_row), 
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_year, invoice_number, payment_row) REFERENCES Payment(invoice_year, invoice_number, payment_row),
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_year, invoice_number) REFERENCES Invoice(invoice_year, invoice_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (sign) REFERENCES Sign(sign_code)
);
```

**Invoice**

```
invoice_year    invoice_number  amount  sign
2018            1               100.2   1
2018            2               98.4    1
```

**Payment**

```
invoice_year    invoice_number  payment_row amount  sign
2018            1               1           50      1
2018            1               2           50.2    1
2018            2               1           90.4    1
2018            2               2           8       1
```

**Taking**

```
taking_year taking_row  invoice_year    invoice_number  payment_row amount  sign
2018        1           2018            1               1           80      1
2018        2           2018            1               1           80      2
2018        3           2018            1               1           25      1
2018        4           2018            1               1           25      1
2018        5           2018            1               2           25.1    1
2018        6           2018            1               2           24.1    1
2018        7           2018            2               1           90.4    1
2018        8           2018            2               2           8       1
```

**Sign**

```
sign_code   sign_value  description
1           1           CREDIT
2           -1          DEBT
```

These are the queries i've wrote

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Invoice AS I
INNER JOIN Sign S1 ON I.sign = S1.sign_code
WHERE I.amount*S1.sign_value - (SELECT SUM(T.amount*S2.sign_value)
                                FROM Taking T
                                INNER JOIN Sign S2 ON T.sign = S2.sign_code
                                WHERE T.invoice_year = I.invoice_year AND T.invoice_number = I.invoice_number
                               ) <> 0;

SELECT I.*
FROM Invoice AS I
INNER JOIN Sign S1 ON I.sign = S1.sign_code
WHERE I.amount*S1.sign_value - (SELECT SUM(T.amount*S2.sign_value)
                                FROM Taking T
                                INNER JOIN Sign S2 ON T.sign = S2.sign_code
                                WHERE T.invoice_year = I.invoice_year AND T.invoice_number = I.invoice_number
                               ) <> 0
```

Also, these entities have composite primary keys and i have to use with doctrine and knp-paginator-bundle so i have to "COUNT" the number of rows

- https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2910
- [Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity using knp paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542653/single-id-is-not-allowed-on-composite-primary-key-in-entity-using-knp-paginator)

Any idea on how to improve at least the execution time?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Nowhere in your SQL is there any correlation between Invoice and Taking.  I don't see any reference to Payment either.  As @GordonLinoff said, can you show some data?

Comment: Take a look to the fiddle there are schema, data and queries. I'm also editing to add tables data.

Comment: @JackSkeletron.. Edit the question with desired result that you want.

Comment: PinnyM has a very valid points, there is no correlation between the Invoice joined to Sign and the sub-query joining Taking to Sign (S2) - that can't be correct.

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: I've updated the Fiddle, now i think i've fixed what i0ve fogotten. Sorry, i'm reverse engineer all the schema (i'm not the DB designer)

Answer (score 0):

Your query ignores the `Payment` `table`. You will need to make sure that the records in the outer `select` are matched against the records in the inner `select`:

```
SELECT I.*
FROM Invoice AS I
INNER JOIN Sign S1 ON I.sign = S1.sign_code
WHERE I.amount*S1.sign_value - (SELECT SUM(T.amount*S2.sign_value)
                                FROM Taking T
                                INNER JOIN Payment P ON T.invoice_year = P.invoice_year and T.invoice_number = P.invoice_number and T.payment_row = P.payment_row and P.invoice_year = I.invoice_year and P.invoice_number = I.invoice_number
                                INNER JOIN Sign S2 ON T.sign = S2.sign_code
                               ) <> 0;
```

Without this part added to your query, the query was obviously incorrect and takes a lot of time to be executed. Also, I recommend not using the `*` operator in SELECT clauses, as they might be unsafe (if there is a `password` field, for instance) and bad for performance (if there is a `column` which holds very large data which is unnecessary for you in this case).

Comment: Sorry, i'm not the designer of the DB, i had to reverse engineer a lot of work. I've edited the schema 'cos i've forgotten `FOREIGN KEY (invoice_year, invoice_number) REFERENCES Invoice(invoice_year, invoice_number)` in Taking entity. I've also corrected the query with the ones i use.

Comment: @JackSkeletron I think you misunderstood my answer. The answer does not criticise the schema, but rather it takes the schema as a situation you need to work with. My answer deals with the problem you have specified in your question. You have observed that your queries are not very performant. However, at least one of the causes and probably the most important cause of this behavior is the fact that your inner query was not only taking the Takings related to the Invoice, but the Takings related to other invoices as well.

Comment: the problem was that i've forgotten, "rewriting" my code in this post and fiddle, some parts such as the where clause in the queries and the FOREIGN KEY  that relates Taking directly to Invoice...

Comment: @JackSkeletron take a look at the query you have shown us in the question and ask yourself: how am I making sure that the inner query will calculate the sum of only those items which are related to the invoice in the outer query? You will see that there is no such guarantee, so your query is incorrect. To correct your query you will need to make sure that the takings you are working with are restricted exactly to the takings which are related to payments which are related to the invoice your query is actually working with. This is the problem I have seen and the problem my answer is solving.

Comment: @JackSkeletron oh, I see. The problem my answer was dealing with was already fixed. Is the performance of your query improving? How is the current performance compared to the performance you had before the fix?

Comment: The "COUNT" query takes ca. 3.5 seconds (3390.08 ms), the SELECT 1.5 seconds (TOT ca. 5 seconds) for first pages (remember i'm using the knp paginator bundle). When executing for the middle pages (click on page 150) only the select takes 15 seconds.

Comment: @JackSkeletron if you rewrite the select clause from select * to select 1 how is the performance modified? (time needed to get all the columns versus some dummy constant)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171167/discussion-between-jack-skeletron-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score -1):

Try a group by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM Invoice AS I
  JOIN Sign S1 
    ON I.sign = S1.sign_code
  JOIN ( SELECT T.invoice_year, T.invoice_number
              , SUM(T.amount*S2.sign_value) as sm
           FROM Taking T
           JOIN Sign S2 
          GROUP BY T.invoice_year, T.invoice_number 
       ) t
   ON T.invoice_year   = I.invoice_year 
  AND T.invoice_number = I.invoice_number
  AND I.amount*S1.sign_value <> t.sm
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried, almost the same result, the count select takes 4 secs (4064.58 ms)

Comment: @JackSkeletron I did not think you did.  No big deal.   You even tested and stated you got the same result.